# Plutus playground error when running simulator: WalletContractError ToCardanoError (Tag \"toCardanoPolicyId\" (Tag \"1 bytes\" DeserialisationError))

Tags: smart-contract, plutus-playground, haskell

Plutus-apps v2022-04-06

My smart contract compiles successfully however when i run the simulator i get this error

```
Contract instance stopped with error: "WalletContractError (ToCardanoError (Tag \"toCardanoPolicyId\" (Tag \"1 bytes\" DeserialisationError)))" ]
```

My plutus code is here: https://github.com/naeri-kailash/elysium-plutus/blob/master/src/Cardano/PlutusExample/Trade.hs

I have read another issue where someone got this error but their solution (CurrencySymbol needed to be changed to a policyID i believe - mine is already a policyID) was not relevant to me. Could I please have some guidance on how to go about debugging this error?

Much appreciated

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the plutus code to reproduce this issue. This way someone could try to help you better.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you @eddex I have added the plutus contract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have instead built the playground using the `plutus-apps` tag referenced in week 1 of the `plutus-pioneer-program`. This solved the issue although I do not know what the problem was with the tag I was using previously (v2022-04-06).

The `plutus-apps` tag that fixed it is `41149926c108c71831cfe8d244c83b0ee4bf5c8a`.

The way I ended up trying this solution was that I tried to run the EnglishAuction contract in week01 content, and I encountered the same error so I then understood that the problem did not explicitly lie in my contract, rather the interaction between the contract and that version of the playground.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
tkSymbol :: CurrencySymbol
tkSymbol = currencySymbol "8d803516132f6fb8ddfcf168065886bf44ecc9e0023b570963b4bac8"

elysiumtitan0 :: KnownCurrency
elysiumtitan0 = KnownCurrency (fromSymbol tkSymbol) "Token" ( (TokenName "ElysiumTitan0") :| [])


elysiumtitan1 :: KnownCurrency
elysiumtitan1 = KnownCurrency (fromSymbol tkSymbol) "Token" ( (TokenName "ElysiumTitan1") :| [])

...
```

Comment: Unfortunately still getting (nearly) the same error, different bytes 
```Contract instance stopped with error: "WalletContractError (ToCardanoError (Tag \"toCardanoPolicyId\" (Tag \"56 bytes\" DeserialisationError)))" ]```

Comment: we can start to trace the error from here [toCardanoPolicyId](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/f592a7b2a97e3e2a318f5585661c5ada1fe9bd43/plutus-ledger/src/Ledger/Tx/CardanoAPI.hs#L648-L649), but i'm not sure which on call to `toCardanoPolicyId`
You can try this [way](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Uniswap/Trace.hs#L66-L88) to generate some token for offchain emulator trace

Comment: I'm having trouble importing the `Plutus.Contracts` module even though its showing in the docs for my version, I'll see if I can get it working and get back to you, thanks :)